# Multiple critieria left join, how to know which criteria is not being met

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, multiple-conditions

I have the following code for a left join on four conditions that need to be met, Id, Contract_Type, Sub_Contract_Number and Percentage.

I have the following Left Join statement:

```
select a.* from table_1 as a
left join table_2 as b
on a.id = b.id
and a.Contract_Type = b.Contract_Type
and a.Sub_Contract_Number = b.Sub_Contract_Number
and a.Percentage = b.Percentage
```

Sample data:

```
Table 1
1    G7   12   .40
1    G7   13   .60

Table 2
1    G7   18   .39
1    G1   13   .61
```

How can I determine which condition was not met by the Left join? I have a huge data set with 9000+ distinct id's, and need to what condition is not met so I can determine what is the difference in the two tables. Also, is there a way to set a range of within one decimal place of the percentage, so it would not show as a difference between the two tables because of a percentage difference of one percent. Thank

Comment: What is your expected output, and how do you want to report partial matches?

Comment: If you drop the conditions from the join then you can select the conditions as booleans from the new result & using that as a subquery group & aggregate on those boolean columns. You're not clear on exactly what the input & output for your desired process is though. Please give a [mcve] with input & desired output & clear specification.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your question can be answered with a simple modification to your query:

```
select a.*
from table_1 a left join
     table_2 b
     on a.id = b.id and
        a.Contract_Type = b.Contract_Type and
        a.Sub_Contract_Number = b.Sub_Contract_Number and
        a.Percentage >= b.Percentage - 0.01 and
        a.Percentage <= b.Percentage + 0.01 ;
```

For the first part of your question, I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  Provide *desired results*.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.